# How to assign "-e" to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variable, echo

I'm trying to assign `-e` to a variable in Bash 4. But the variable remains empty.

For example:

```
$ var="-e" 
$ echo $var

$ var='-e' 
$ echo $var

$ var="-t" 
$ echo $var
-t
```

Why does it work with `-t`, but not `-e`?

Comment: Outputting the variable with `echo` would output nothing, but the variable has the value `-e` (which is a valid option for `echo` in `bash`). You'd have the same issue with `-n` and `-E` and combinations thereof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, but running `echo -e` doesn't output anything in Bash unless both the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are enabled, as the `-e` is then interpreted as an option:

```
$ help echo
echo: echo [-neE] [arg ...]
    Write arguments to the standard output.

    Display the ARGs, separated by a single space character and followed by a
    newline, on the standard output.

    Options:
      -n        do not append a newline
      -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
      -E        explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Use

```
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

instead.

And as cas notes in a comment, Bash's `declare -p var` (`typeset -p var` in ksh, zsh and yash (and bash)) can be used to tell the exact type and contents of a variable.

See: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

Comment: also, if the OP wants to verify that $var does indeed contain `-e`, they can run `declare -p var`.

Answer (score 0):

A command (like your `echo`) takes command line arguments which could be flags (`-e` in your case). Many commands (at least common Linux versions) understand `--` (two hyphens) as "end of flags, whatever follows is regular arguments". So you can delete a file perversely named `-r` by `rm -- -r`.

For displaying stuff, `printf` is more robust all around (if harder to use).